# Matlab Crash in RegressionTree mex file

Tags: matlab, debugging, machine-learning, regression, mex

I'm trying to implement a classifier on matlab that uses RegressionTrees as a part of its procedure.
Now i'm getting an exception in the mex file of the regression tree.

here is a part of the crash dump

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Tue Jun  4 11:49:48 2013
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Current Visual     : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding   : UTF-8
  GNU C Library      : 2.13 stable
  MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
  MATLAB Root        : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Linux 3.0.0-31-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 20:02:57 UTC 2013 x86_64
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (11004000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 000000000a673ad8  RBX = 0000000008c85de8
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00000000000002a5
  RSP = 00007f5fa88ba8e0  RBP = 00007f5fa88ba910
  RSI = 0000000008c85de8  RDI = 0000000008c825a0

   R8 = 0000000008c825a0   R9 = 0000000000003870
  R10 = 0000000000003001  R11 = ffefffffffffffff
  R12 = 0000000008c83ac0  R13 = 0000000008c83ac8
  R14 = 00007f5fa88ba930  R15 = 0000000000000119

  RIP = 00007f5f7a06e9fd  EFL = 0000000000010246

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f5f7a06e9fd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00088573 _ZSt9__find_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPmSt6vectorImSaImEEEEN12classregtree12IndexedIsNaNIdEEET_SA_SA_T0_St26random_access_iterator_tag+00000077
[  1] 0x00007f5f7a06eb29 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00088873 _ZSt9remove_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPmSt6vectorImSaImEEEEN12classregtree12IndexedIsNaNIdEEET_SA_SA_T0_+00000041
[  2] 0x00007f5f7a085f20 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00184096
[  3] 0x00007f5f7a0cf25b /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00483931
[  4] 0x00007f5f7a0d0580 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00488832
[  5] 0x00007f5f7a0eb2c6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00598726
[  6] 0x00007f5f7a0698a3 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+learning/+treeutils/growTree.mexa64+00067747 mexFunction+00001939
[  7] 0x00007f5fb2a1bf8a     /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00110474 mexRunMexFile+00000090
[  8] 0x00007f5fb2a180f9     /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00094457
[  9] 0x00007f5fb2a18f1c     /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00098076
[ 10] 0x00007f5fbc2ac6b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
[ 11] 0x00007f5fb2ff453a  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01672506
[ 12] 0x00007f5fb2f9513a  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01282362
[ 13] 0x00007f5fb2f953be  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01283006
[ 14] 0x00007f5fb2f9712c  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01290540
[ 15] 0x00007f5fb3002246  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01729094
[ 16] 0x00007f5fb3081cd8  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+02251992
[ 17] 0x00007f5fbc25eaf8 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00244472 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000488
[ 18] 0x00007f5fbbb4a256 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02245206
[ 19] 0x00007f5fbbafaa86 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01919622
...
...
```

The complete crash dump http://snipt.org/AlK6

Now how can i know if my whether my input to the regression Tree is causing an error or it is something related to my hardware ?
is There a way to know the reason of the error ?

---

**UPDATE**

here are the lines that cause the exception (the Regression Tree line is the main reason)

```
for j = 1:J
    save('data');
    gj = RegressionTree.fit(trainData, Y_CODE(:, j), 'Weights', wts);
    g{j} = gj;
end
```

This code snippet is a part of a loop (actually i'm trying to implement [GAMBLE](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/78965/SDM2007.pdf) algorithm, if you know an existing implementation that would be great), and matlab crashes everytime in a different iteration..

I have tried to save the workspace `save('data')` and re-execute the regression tree line after restarting matlab but it didn't crash .. which is very strange. 
i have sent a crash report to MathWorks.

meanwhile is there a matlab implementation of Regression Trees that supports weights ? or better an implementation of the [GAMBLE](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/78965/SDM2007.pdf) boosting algorithm ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your code? Rather, what is the simplest code that causes the crash -including inputs to the functions? Have you checked that the inputs are all of the correct datatype/class and dimension? That could easily kill a badly written mex file. Regardless, the code should not crash under any circumstances and this should be [reported to The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do).

Comment: @horchler i have updated the question with the lines causing the crash and explained what i was trying to implement, i also sent a crash report to MathWorks. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're running on a system that meets the published [MATLAB system requirements](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux), no MathWorks code should really be giving you a segmentation violation like this - whatever input you are passing into it. Even if you're passing in complete nonsense, it should stop gracefully with a MATLAB error, not a hard fault like this.

If you can reproduce the behaviour (in a freshly started MATLAB, nothing else running, with the same inputs each time), contact MathWorks support to either discover whether an aspect of your system is unsupported, or to report a bug.

Comment: My system meets the published requirements (except that i'm using ubuntu 11.10 not 12.04).  i have sent them a crash report, but i can't reproduce the bug as occurs in a different iteration every time, but i can send them the whole code if it can helps.. can you see the question after the edits and tell me your opinion ? or whether you know an existing implementation of RegressionTrees ? Thanks

Comment: I would say that if can reproducibly run the same piece of code, on a freshly started MATLAB, and every time you get the same segmentation violation (whether or not it occurs on the same iteration) then you have a reproducible issue that should be reported to MathWorks. I would also tell them your finding regarding the `save` command, in case it's relevant.

Comment: I imagine Ubuntu 11 is OK as it is kernel 2.6, but make sure you have glibc 2.5 or later.